# Manually rewrite requests to specific URLs in Browsersync

Tags: javascript, express, browser-sync

I'm using BrowserSync in a somewhat strange setup, where I'm proxying my web server (Apache in a Docker container), but also serving hot module replacement (HMR) from a Webpack dev server.

In my local dev environment, the setup looks something like this:

`https://mytestsite.localhost` – an Apache service in a Docker container

`https://localhost:8888` – Webpack Dev server, serving HMR

`https://localhost:3000` – BrowserSync`

For hard reloads, this all works fine – the webpack dev server appears to pass on the message that a reload is needed and all is well.

The issue that I'm having is with hot reloads. The document being served by the BS proxy should be reading the `hotupdate.json` served by webpack-dev-server. On receiving a hot update, the page tries to load `/hotupdate.json` (which I believe tells it which snippet of code to pick up), however, because it's a relative URL, the browser tries to `GET https://localhost:3000/hotupdate.json`, which 404s, because this `hotupdate.json` is actually served by the Webpack server, e.g. `https://localhost:8888/hotupdate.json`.

Because I know the absolute URL to this resource, I'd like to force BrowserSync to redirect any requests to `/hotupdate.json` to `https://localhost:8888/hotupdate.json`. I thought I could do this with some middleware, but I'm struggling, possibly because I've never fully groked Express-style middleware.

I've tried something like this, but no worky!

```
browserSync({
    proxy: {
        target: `https://${process.env.APP_HOST_PATH}`,
        middleware: [
            dontProxyHotUpdate,
            require('webpack-dev-middleware')(bundler, {
                noInfo: true,
                publicPath: webpackConfig.output.path
            }),
        ]
    },
    files: [
      'app/css/*.css',
      'app/*.html'
    ]
});

function dontProxyHotUpdate (req, res, next){
    if(req.url === '/hotupdate.json'){
        req.url = 'https://127.0.0.1:8888/hotupdate.json';
    }
    next();
}
```

It definitely loads the middleware as I can, say, `console.log(req.url)`, but I'm not able to rewrite the request URL. I suppose possible solutions would either be to rewrite the request URL, or to overwrite the response directly.

N.B. One might ask why I'm not using webpack-dev-server directly, as it serves HMR nicely on its own. It does, but it also doesn't allow for nice rewriting of the anchor elements within a page, e.g. changing `https://mytestsite.localhost/link` to `https://localhost:3000/link`. This is important obviously for navigating through a site while developing (which is nice, but not essential), but even more important for rewriting links to assets – SVGs, in particular, which won't load unless the path, host and port all match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I sorted my own problem!

I ended up writing my own middleware using `http-proxy-middlware` - like this.

```
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

browserSync({
    proxy: {
        target: `https://${process.env.APP_HOST_PATH}`,
        middleware: [
            dontProxyHotUpdate,
            require('webpack-dev-middleware')(bundler, {
                noInfo: true,
                publicPath: webpackConfig.output.path
            }),
            // require("webpack-hot-middleware")(bundler) // I don't think that we want this here as it can be handled by the webpack dev server
        ],
    },

    // no need to watch '*.js' here, webpack will take care of it for us,
    // including full page reloads if HMR won't work
    files: [
      path.join(source, '**/*.php'),
      path.join(source, 'style.css')
    ]
});

var dontProxyHotUpdate = proxy('/hotupdate*', {
    target: 'https://127.0.0.1:8888/',
    changeOrigin: true, // for vhosted sites, changes host header to match to target's host
    logLevel: 'debug',
    secure: false
});
```